# Get image source from XML and load it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, image

I have the following XML file

```
<PRODUCT>
      <IMAGE><image href="myimage.jpg"/></IMAGE>
      <NAME>TV 47" LCD Full HD Scarlet</NAME>
      <PRICE>4999</PRICE>
</PRODUCT>
```

As you can see, my  element has a href. I can easily get the text data from NAME and PRICE. Now I need to get the href attribute from  and load it. This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{ 
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) 
    {
        $(xml).find('PRODUCT').each(function() 
        {
            var name = $(this).find('NAME').text();
            var price = $(this).find('PRICE').text();
            var image = $(this).find('IMAGE').text();
            $('<p></p>').html(name+'<br />'+price+'<br />'+image).appendTo('#wrap');
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

How do I extract the href attribute and load the corresponding image into a div "wrap"? 
I tried this [Implementing Images in HTML using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150028/implementing-images-in-html-using-xml) but doesn't work. thank you guys

Comment: you should replace your every .find() function from .children()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the href attribute this way

```
var image = $(xml).find("image[href]").attr("href");
```

Load the content to the div this way

```
$('#wrap').append($("<img src=\"" +image+"\"/>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var image = $(this).find('IMAGE').children().attr("href");
```

**To create Object**

```
imgobject=$("<img />").attr("src",image);
```

Comment: should I create an Image object from the var ?

Comment: my div displays [object object] in the place of the image, do you now what is happening?

Comment: it depends how are you inserting the image in the div .Tell me the syntax you are using to insert

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var imgUrl = $(xml).find("image[href]").attr("href"); 
$yourdiv.append($("<img src=\"" + imgUrl + "\"/>"));
```

Hope it's helpful.